# mysql unable to start with semi sync parameter

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid, semi-sync-replication

Im using mysql 5.7 and it has 2 slaves with GTID. I tried to enable semi-sync and I have done with `set global variable` in mysql prompt. It was running fine. Then I did a restart, after that mysql unable to start and it says `unknown variable 'rpl-semi-sync-master-enabled=1'`

### mysql log

```
2018-11-03T08:28:35.453089Z 5 [Note] Start binlog_dump to master_thread_id(5) slave_server(2), pos(, 4)
2018-11-03T08:28:35.453119Z 5 [Note] Start asynchronous binlog_dump to slave (server_id: 2), pos(, 4)
2018-11-03T08:28:35.793103Z 6 [Note] Start binlog_dump to master_thread_id(6) slave_server(3), pos(, 4)
2018-11-03T08:28:35.793141Z 6 [Note] Start semi-sync binlog_dump to slave (server_id: 3), pos(, 4)
2018-11-03T08:29:25.656749Z 0 [Note] Giving 5 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2018-11-03T08:29:25.656793Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2018-11-03T08:29:33.658167Z 5 [Note] Stop asynchronous binlog_dump to slave (server_id: 2)
2018-11-03T08:29:33.658360Z 6 [Note] Stop semi-sync binlog_dump to slave (server_id: 3)
2018-11-03T08:29:35.658275Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2018-11-03T08:29:35.658368Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2018-11-03T08:29:35.658532Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-11-03T08:29:35.662977Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'rpl_semi_sync_slave'
2018-11-03T08:29:35.663025Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'rpl_semi_sync_master'
2018-11-03T08:29:35.663059Z 0 [Note] unregister_replicator OK
2018-11-03T08:29:35.663062Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
```

### syslog:

```
Nov  3 04:11:17   mysql-systemd-start[9868]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Nov  3 04:11:17 mysql-systemd-start[9868]: 2018-11-03T04:11:17.961175Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'rpl-semi-sync-master-enabled=1'
Nov  3 04:11:17   mysql-systemd-start[9868]: 2018-11-03T04:11:17.964899Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

### Update:

I used the lines then it worked. But what is the use of these parameters?

```
loose-rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled = 1
loose-rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled = 1
```

Comment: Was that syslog from the Slave?

Comment: It's from the master server, in Slave also I got similar error